# How to create a function in Python3 to return a substring from a string between two markers using regular expression?

Tags: python-3.x, substring, user-defined-functions

I want to create a function in Python3, that will take 3 inputs: marker1, marker2, text and will return the substring between the 2 markers

```
def findText(marker1, marker2, text):
    m = re.search(marker1(.+?)marker2, text)
    if m:
        found = m.group(1)
        print(found)  #print what was found
        return(found)
```

I expect when I call:

```
print(findText("AAA", "BBB", "thisisAAAtestTextOnlyBBBxyz"))
```

to show:

```
testTextOnly
```

Comment: Works fine...What is the issue?

Comment: `re.search(marker1(.+?)marker2, text)` will throw a syntax error, can you check your code again? Unless you do `re.search('{}(.+?){}'.format(marker1, marker2), text)` which works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

def findText(marker1, marker2, text):
    search_for = r".+" + marker1 + r"(.+?)" + marker2 + ".+"
    m = re.search(search_for, text)
    if m:
        found = m.group(1)
        print(found)  #print what was found
        return(found)

findText("AAA", "BBB", "thisisAAAtestTextOnlyBBBxyz")
```

result:
`testTextOnly`